# Solve complex matrix differential equation with Odeint

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I want to solve a matrix differential equation, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319996/solving-matrix-differential-equation-in-python-using-scipy-numpy-ndsolve-equiva):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint


def deriv(A, t, Ab):
    return np.dot(Ab, A)


Ab = np.array([[-0.25,    0,    0],
               [ 0.25, -0.2,    0],
               [    0,  0.2, -0.1]])

time = np.linspace(0, 25, 101)
A0 = np.array([10, 20, 30])

MA = odeint(deriv, A0, time, args=(Ab,))
```

However, this does not work in the case of having complex matrix elements. I am looking for something similar to [`scipy.integrate.complex_ode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.complex_ode.html) but for `odeint`. If this is not possible, what other library should I use to perform the integration? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Several related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742818/solve-ode-in-python-with-complex-matrix-as-initial-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580854/how-to-plot-the-eigenvalues-when-solving-matrix-coupled-differential-equations-i, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910189/scipy-odeint-with-complex-initial-values (and there are more).  In those questions, I suggested using the wrapper that I wrote called [`odeintw`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser This approach requires to write the matrix as a function, right? My problem is that I have 150x150 matrices and writing each them as python functions is way too time-consuming. Also computing the jacobian demands a lot of time. Is there a way of using your wrapper similar to what you proposed in that question I mention in mine? i.e. sth like `MA = odeint(deriv, A0, time, args=(Ab,))` Thanks

Comment: *"This approach requires to write the matrix as a function, right?"* No, do what you are already doing, but with complex coefficients in the array `Ab`.  Then also make `A0` complex, and `odeintw` should Just Work.

Comment: *"Also computing the jacobian demands a lot of time."*  You don't have to provide the Jacobian function.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks, at first I did not make A0 complex. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`odeintw`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw) wrapper for `odeint` must be used in the same fashion as in the question. However, the initial value `A0` must be complex-valued vector.

Comment: Actually, `Ab` does not have to be complex.  I only suggested that in my comment to the question because you said your actual array would be complex.  It is the initial condition `A0` that *must* be complex.  That's how `odeintw` knows you are using complex variables.